# How can I make this function change my input's value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just getting into JavaScript and I was trying to make a background color generator which is randomized by a button. When this button is pressed, both inputs (color1 & color2) get a random value and it's reflected on the body's style.

This is my code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Gradient Background</title>
</head>
<body id="gradient">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Background Generator</h1>
        <input class="color1" id="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#ff0000">
        <input class="color2" id="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#ffff00">

        <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
        <h3></h3>
        <button id="button" class="button">Randomize</button>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var css = document.querySelector("h3");
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
var body = document.getElementById("gradient");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var inputColor1 = document.getElementById("color1");
var inputColor2 = document.getElementById("color2");

function setGradient() {
    body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + color1.value + ", " + color2.value + ")";

    css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
}

color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
color2.addEventListener("input", setGradient);


inputColor1.value = generateRandomColor().value;
inputColor2.value = generateRandomColor().value;

function generateRandomColor(){
    let maxVal = 0xFFFFFF; // 16777215
    let randomNumber = Math.random() * maxVal; 
    randomNumber = Math.floor(randomNumber);
    randomNumber = randomNumber.toString(16);
    let randColor = randomNumber.padStart(6, 0);   
    return `#${randColor.toUpperCase()}`
}
// console.log(generateRandomColor()); 

button.addEventListener("click", generateRandomColor);
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two colors you need to randomize, so you need to call `generateRandomColor` twice, not once. You also need to set the resulting values to both inputs and call `setGradient` again.

```js
const css = document.querySelector("h3");
const color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
const color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
const body = document.getElementById("gradient");
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const inputColor1 = document.getElementById("color1");
const inputColor2 = document.getElementById("color2");

function setGradient() {
  document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + color1.value + ", " + color2.value + ")";

  css.textContent = document.body.style.background + ";";
}
setGradient();

color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
color2.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
function generateRandomColor() {
  const maxVal = 0xFFFFFF; // 16777215
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxVal).toString(16);
  const randColor = randomNumber.padStart(6, 0);
  return `#${randColor.toUpperCase()}`
}
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  inputColor1.value = generateRandomColor();
  inputColor2.value = generateRandomColor();
  setGradient();
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Background Generator</h1>
  <input class="color1" id="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#ff0000">
  <input class="color2" id="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#ffff00">

  <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
  <h3></h3>
  <button id="button" class="button">Randomize</button>
</div>
```